# Function returns poorly formed dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function `get_test_data()` that is supposed to return me a dict

```
return [{headers[test_name_index - 1]: test_name[i], headers[test_data_index - 1]: test_data[i]} for i in range(len(test_name))]
```

Returns `[{u'Test1': u'1', u'Test2': u'2'}, {u'Test1': u'3', u'Test2': u'4'}]`

Except when I try to access the values...

```
test = {}
test.update(get_test_data())
print test
print test['Test1'][0]
print test.keys()
print test.values()
```

I get...

```
{u'Test1': u'Test2'}
T
[u'Test1']
[u'Test2']
```

What I want...

```
{'Test1': 1, 'Test2': 2}, {'Test1': 3, 'Test2': 4}
1
[u'Test1', u'Test2']
[u'1','2','3','4']
```

How can I set up my the last return statement of my function right so that I can access the dict keys and values properly?

Comment: You are returning a list, not a dict.

Comment: Ah OK, I was sent down this path by another user. How should I be saving this data type then? - If I have duplicate keys?

Comment: And what are the keys supposed to be?

Comment: A representation of a table. The keys are the table headers.

Comment: But what key should be where?

Comment: Are you looking for https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6calling update on list just keeps overwriting as you have duplicate keys, if you want a dict of dicts use `enumerate`:

```
test = {}
test.update(enumerate(get_test_data()))
```

That will give you:

```
{0: {u'Test1': u'1', u'Test2': u'2'}, 1: {u'Test1': u'3', u'Test2': u'4'}}
```

where the indexes are the outer keys. You cannot have duplicate keys and both dicts have the same keys so there seems no logical reason as to where you would get the keys from.

Alternatively to enumerate, you could use a dict comp:

```
test = {"dict_{}".format(d["Test2"]) : d for d in get_test_data()}
```

...to have str names for the outer dictionaries.

Comment: OK this structure works for me. Is there any way to change the outer keys from int to str, based on the 'Test2' value of each dict? Say strings like 'Dict-2', 'Dict-4'

Comment: There is no second value unless you mean the world test2 key as dicts are unordered, that itself could cause issues if two values are the same

Comment: The value of Test2 in each dict - 2, 4 for example

Comment: What happens if they are both the same?

Comment: I will make sure they aren't. If you consider my example of representing a table, the outer keys will be named after table row headers. Which I will make unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98749/discussion-between-square-eyes-and-padraic-cunningham).